# No response on xhttp.open function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

When trying to use a function which adds a element to a table and shows the table in a section of the site it does nothing. It should get the date from the currently selected, the id of active tr element and the name of the current logged in user. Send it to a php file which would insert into the table "kalendar" the selected date, the recipe id and the client id and then make a table in the aside with the id of "recipes_for_day". Its not adding anything to the table kalendar and because of that its not showing the new table. I apologize for the spaghetti code, its my first time using ajax.

```js
function addRecipe(a){
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let d = new Date();
        d.setDate(weekday.getDate + a);
        var header=document.getElementById("scroll")
        var activetr= header.getElementsByClassName("tr active");
        var trid = activetr.getAttribute('id');
        var str="q="+d.toString()+"?"+"w="+trid+"?user="+$_SESSION['login_user']; 
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById("recipes_for_day").prepend(div); 
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "addrecipe.php?"+str, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

spoj.php just connects to the database

```js
    require_once "spoj.php";
    
    $RecipeId = "SELECT Id FROM recipe where Name = ?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmd,"s", $_GET['w'])
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($RecipeId);
    
    $UserId = "SELECT Id FROM korisnici where Username = ?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmd,"s", $_GET['user'])
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($UserId);
    
    $sql="INESRT INTO kalendar('Date','RecipeId', 'ClientId') VALUES(?,".$RecipeId.",".$UserId."')";
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmd,"s", $_GET['q']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    "<div class='container'>
        <table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Calories per 100g</th>
                        <th>Fat</th>
                        <th>Carbohydrate</th>
                        <th>Diatery fiber</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>";
                while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo'
                    <tr id="savedrecipe" onlick="showMax();" onmousedown="removeRecipe("'.$_GET['q'].'","'.$row["Name"].'");">
                        <td>'.$row["Name"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Calories"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Fat"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Carbohydrate"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["DiateryFiber"].'</td>
                </tr>';}
            echo'</tbody>
        </table>
    </div>';
}
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
```

```html
          <ul class="list-group" id="weekly_meal_plan">
<li id="first" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="showTable(0);" onmousedown="addRecipe(0);"></li>
<li id="second" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="showTable(1);" onmousedown="addRecipe(1);"></li>
<li id="third" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="showTable(2);" onmousedown="addRecipe(2);"></li>
<li id="fourth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="showTable(3);" onmousedown="addRecipe(3);"></li>
<li id="fifth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="showTable(4);" onmousedown="addRecipe(4);"></li>
<li id="sixth" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="showTable(5);" onmousedown="addRecipe(5);"></li>
<li id="seventh" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="showTable(6);" onmousedown="addRecipe(6);"></li>
</ul>
<br>

<aside style="float:right;" id="recipes_for_day">
        
</aside>
```

Comment: You never assign `xhttp`

Comment: Its in the global variables. i just forgot to add it in here. Sorry about that, i have been working on this 9 hours now so I'm a bit tired.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to reuse the same `XMLHttpRequest` object. You should create a new one each time you want to send an AJAX request.

Comment: @Bamar While ill take this advice and use it, it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Anything in your console? Did you try step through debugging? Maybe add some `console.log()` statements to find out if your onreadystatechange handler gets reached?

Comment: @Evert What program do you recommend for it? I've been just using xampp and looking at the website to see if it works. I would love something like visualstudio to run it since im using notepad++.

Comment: I forgot about conles on websites. Sorry about that.

Comment: Every browser has step-through debugging and a console.

Comment: So activetr.getAttribute() is not a function and Uncaught ReferenceError: $_SESSION is not defined

Comment: I made the mistake of using ˘_SESSION inside javascript insted of php.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` before `xhttp.onreadystatechange`

Comment: Its in the global variables. i forgot to add them, sorry about that. There are also global variables days, elemen, weeknumber, and weekday.

Comment: then you should abort (`xhttp.abort()`) the previous connection, or create a new local one.

Comment: I created a new local xhttp variable for each function that used it and deleted the global one, like @Bamar suggested but it still doesnt fix the problem.

Comment: @BottomCroat update your question with the new code.

Comment: Others are right, you should check your console, I also think it is a issue of CORS

Comment: So activetr.getAttribute() addRecipe is not a function and Uncaught ReferenceError: $_SESSION is not defined at showTable.

Comment: im looking through the api of getAttribute to see whats wrong.

Comment: what is that `var str="q="+d.toString()+"?"+"w="+trid+"?user="+$_SESSION['login_user'];` ! how can you directly print php session inside a js function !  wrap it inside <?php .. ?>

Comment: used $_Session inside javascript insted of php

Comment: that was the mistake.